# Listar terms de taxonomies relacionados ao post_type específico Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-types

Olá, eu tenho que listar todos os terms de 4 taxonomias, porém eles tem que pertencer a um post type específico!

Por exemplo, eu tenho as seguintes informações:

post_type ( graduacao, pos_graduacao )
 taxonomia (local, unidade)

Já pesquisei em tudo que é lugar, e não consegui encontrar o que procuro..

Eu quero listar todos os termos que tiver post marcado como taxonomia: local e e que pertença a graduacao;
Tentei o get_terms, wp_get_post_terms, fiz diversos testes e loops e nenhum me trouxe a lista que preciso.

Se puderem me ajudar, agradeço muito!
Obs. as taxonomias estão relacionadas a todos os post types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom pessoal, para quem tiver a mesma dúvida que eu um dia, eu consegui resolver usando uma função bem interessante:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168114/how-to-get-a-list-of-term-names-of-the-custom-post-type-im-currently-on-in-singl

e fiz um outro método que postei aqui no site:

http://desenvolvimentopuro.com.br/buscando-termos-de-taxonomias-relacionados-ao-post-type/

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que vc precise fazer a consutla pelo `tax_query`

```
$posts = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'graduacao',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'nome-taxonomia', //o nome da sua taxonomia
                'field' => 'term_id', // id do campo da taxonomia...
                'terms' => 'local', // o termo da taxonomia
            )
        )
    )
);
```

estou considerando que local é um item dentro de uma taxonomia chamada `nome-taxonomia`

Comment: Na verdade não, eu preciso listar todos os termos,  por exemplo, com o get_terms eu consigo trazer todos os termos cadastrados de todas as taxonomias e fazer um select. Beleza... Só que eu não consigo puxar todos esses termos relativos ao post type que eu quiser.. entendeu? Preciso que ele me traga uma lista de termos relacionados ao post type específico

Comment: O tax_query eu uso para trazer posts específicos do termos, no caso, é quase ao contrário..rs trazer todos e somente os termos do post_type específico

Comment: vc chegou a ver a função [get_object_taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies), aparentemente faz o que vc quer.  Essa eu não testei...

Comment: Tentei algo como: 

    global $post;
     $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'pos_graduacao', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
     while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
     $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $nd_learning_tax);

ele até traz alguns, mas não ta trazendo todos os termos que são referente ao post type..  rs Difícil

Comment: get_terms em geral, sem argumentos.. eu testei quase todos e tbm não deu certo